# Word for "surround in such a way as to reduce the prominence of the surrounded object"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> [...] between taller, more impressive architecture, the building
>   looked nondescript.

I'm pretty sure there's a word for that. A word that has *hide* and *surround* mixed together. The only word I can think of is *enveloped*, but *enveloped between buildings* sounds strange.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 'Embedded'. "Embedded among taller, more impressive buildings..." or "Embedded in taller, more impressive architecture...". 'Enveloped' also sounds fine to me, changing 'between' to 'in' for "architecture", or to 'by' for "buildings".

Comment: Another option is *engulfed*: (often passive) to overwhelm: engulfed by the impressive achitecture  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/engulfed

Comment: I'm with @JEL I think enveloped works just fine for this. Not that you couldn't use another word if you prefer but I don't think enveloped is out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overshadow comes to mind, for your example.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices:

- Concealed
- Cucooned
- Dwarfed
- Overwhelmed
- Quelled
- Smothered
- **Stifled** *(I personally like this one, feels a bit poetic)*
- Strangled
- Subdued

Pick one that is closest to the feeling you wish to convey.